# Heroku docker image requires an open port

Tags: python, docker, heroku, configuration

I have a simple bot hosted on Docker, it's a single file script that does not require any web service. I deployed it on Heroku but it keeps crashing and due to a missing port:

[image]

I have the following config vars:

[image]

I have tried exposing a port on Docker `EXPOSE $PORT` which has not worked. Is there a way I can have this script run on Heroku without regular crashes due to a missing port?

Comment: No, I have not been successful

Comment: Did you try everything I described in my answer? That should get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two issues here:

1. When you set an environment variable, don't set `process.env.FOO`. Just set `FOO`. This creates (or updates) an environment variable. In JavaScript code you would *access* environment variables via `process.env`, but that isn't part of their name.

   You can do this in the web UI, as you show in your screenshot, or via [the `heroku config` command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#set-a-config-var), e.g.

   ```
   heroku config:set FOO=bar
   ```
2. In this specific case, you're trying to use the `PORT` environment variable backwards. **You don't get to pick your port on Heroku.** *Heroku* picks a port and assigns it to you by setting `PORT`. Your code must respect whatever value that variable has.

   Assuming you're using Express (based on your use of `process.env`) you'll want something like this:

   ```
   const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

   express().listen(PORT);
   ```

   You have also tagged your question with [python](/questions/tagged/python). In that case you can do something like

   ```py
   import os

   port = os.getenv('PORT', default='5000')
   ```

   and then use `port` with whatever web server you're using.

Answer (score 0):

did you set the value $PORT in the dockerfile or passing it as env argument(-e) when running your container. I think its trying to bind $PORT and not the actual port.

Comment: I passed the value $PORT, how can I pass in the env variable to the dockerfile.

Comment: docker run --env "PORT=5000" my_image:my_tag

Comment: I have tried running this command on Heroku but still my bot service crashes

Comment: hey read the port forwarding section in this link(https://deparkes.co.uk/2018/05/28/deploy-docker-to-heroku/)